# Is there a way in python to expand data frame rows and columns at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying add a constant array to a number and add the same constant array to the output array,...

Let's say I start from 18 and add `[-6,0,6]` to it. Results would be: `[(18,12),(18,18),(18,12)]`. In next step I will add the same `[-6,0,6]` to the last output.
So I will have:

```
[(18,24,30),(18,24,24),(18,24,18),(18,18,24),(18,18,18),(18,18,12),(18,12,18),(18,12,12),(18,12,6)]
```

For first step, I tried the following code, but it is not working:

```py
iSOC=18
tSOC=42
step1=6
df=pd.DataFrame(iSOC)
df.insert(iSOC-step1,iSOC,iSOC+step1)
```

Comment: How are we supposed to guess how at first you don't change the size of the output and by doing the same you extend the size by 1 ?

Comment: You are right! It's size is changing. It starts with a number. Changes to 3*2 and in the very next step, the size is: 9*3,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a [sample of code](https://onlinegdb.com/r10peV87H)

```py
def myFunction(base, plus):
    #Initialize result array
    result = []
    #For Each tuple in entry
    for bas in base:
        #Get Last Element
        lastElem = bas[-1:][0]
        #For Each element to add
        for x in plus:
            # Append a tuple composed of base + sum(lastElement & element to add)
            result.append(bas + ( (lastElem+x),) )
    # Return result
    return result
```

which returns

```py
first_elem = [(18,)]   
add = [6,0,-6]
print(myFunction(first_elem, [6,0,-6]))
#[(18, 24), (18, 18), (18, 12)]
print(myFunction([(18, 24), (18, 18), (18, 12)], [6,0,-6]))
#[(18, 24, 30), (18, 24, 24), (18, 24, 18), (18, 18, 24), (18, 18, 18), (18, 18, 12), (18, 12, 18), (18, 12, 12), (18, 12, 6)]
```